# Does ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync work in WebForms running in 4.6.1?

Tags: asp.net, azure, freeze, azure-table-storage, .net-4.6.1

I have an old webforms app that I maintain.  I need to access some data we now store in Azure table storage.  The application is built against 4.6.1 and references WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3.
Assuming an account with a table and a query defined, when I run the following code, the first returns quickly, and the other hangs.  If I remove

`<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />`

both sets of code return.  The problem is that without running in 4.6.1 it defaults to 4.0 which doesn't support TLS 1.2.

The Code:

```
TableContinuationToken token = null;
do
{
    var segment = cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmented<T>(tableQuery, token);
    token = segmentAsync.ContinuationToken;
} while (token != null);

token = null;
do
{
    var segmentAsync = await cloudTable.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<T>(tableQuery, token);
    token = segmentAsync.ContinuationToken;
} while (token != null);
```

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with Webforms or Azure Table Storage. The only relevant part is that without `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />` your runtime reverts acts like it's 4.0. Where are you running your application? Which runtime version are you using? You can't have 4.0 - 4.x runtimes are binary replacements which means installing a new one replaces the previous one and *all* .NET 4.x applications run on top of the new one.

Comment: `Async` doesn't affect TLS either - *both* calls make the *same* HTTP**S** call. The first one blocks waiting for a response while the second one doesn't. Both would throw if TLS1.2 wasn't available.

Comment: How do you call this snippet? Is it part of an `async Task` method? How is *that* one called? Inside a console program, a test runner, an async event handler in a desktop app? Perhaps what you see is a deadlock in the calling code. At the very least, log each iteration. Use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to monitor the HTTP calls and see what's actually going on.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The reason I referenced the change in runtime, is that I don't see the hang when I don't specify the runtime, but I do when I explicitly use 4.6.  I further pointed that out to say I wasn't just changing the runtime for the fun of it, but because 4.0 doesn't support TLS 1.2 by default.  Neither of those relate to the Async, but the hang does.  That addresses the first and second comment.  As for the third, I will update my code to be more complete, though I think asking for more details instead of railing on the question would be more productive.

Answer (score 1):

The method `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` does work in WebForms running in .NET framework 4.6.1.

I'm using `WindowsAzure.Storage 9.3.3`, and without removing `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />`, and it can work.

**Note:** This is just a simple test code to prove `ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync` can work. If you still have issues, please provide the completed code.

The simple code in `Default.aspx.cs` -> `Page_Load` method:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebApplication15
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string connstr = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxx;AccountKey=xxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connstr);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("test22");

            TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query =
                    new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(
                            TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "r1")
                        );

            TableContinuationToken token = null;
            do
            {
                var segment = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented<CustomerEntity>(query, token);
                token = segment.ContinuationToken;
            } while (token != null);

            token = null;
            do
            {
                var segmentAsync = table.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync<CustomerEntity>(query, token).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                token = segmentAsync.ContinuationToken;
            } while (token != null);

        }

    }
}
```

The result:

[image]